# Segmentation Fault 11 when telnetting in (C)

Tags: c, telnet

I'm just learning how to create servers in C and I keep getting a "segmentation fault: 11" error when i try telnetting into this server from another terminal. any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *advice[] = {
        "Take smaller bites\r\n",
        "Go for the tight jeans. No they do NOT make you look fat.\r\n",
        "One word: inappropriate\r\n",
        "Just for today, be honest. Tell your boss what you *really* think\r\n",
        "You might want to rethink that haircut\r\n"
    };
    int listener_d = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in name;
    name.sin_family = PF_INET;
    name.sin_port = (in_port_t)htons(30000);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(listener_d, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name))== -1)
        error("Cannot bind");

    if (listen(listener_d, 10) == -1)
        error("Cannot listen");
    puts("Waiting connection");
    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
        unsigned int address_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        int connect_d = accept(listener_d, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &address_size);
        char msg = advice[0];

        if (send(connect_d, msg, strlen(msg), 0) == -1)
            error("Cannot send");
        close(connect_d);
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const char * msg = advice[0];` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

You're storing `advice[0]` into a `char` rather than a `char *`. It won't fit, and is truncated, making the pointer invalid. Store it in a `char *` (or even `const char *`) instead.

I'd also recommend turning on warnings in your compiler, since they would have caught this mistake. For GCC and Clang, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @AdamLiss: I'm not saying that's illegitimate. I'm saying `char msg = advice[0];` is.

Comment: Thank you so much!! i don't know how i didn't see that. knew i was running out of space somewhere.

Comment: @AdamLiss I must have missed something. I would buy your comment for `char msg = advice[0][0];` but how is storing a `const char*` into a `char` variable "legitimate" ?

Comment: @maston67 how did this even *compile* with you passing `strlen()` a non-pointer in the first place??

Comment: @WhozCraig: Try compiling `int main(int argc, char **argv) { char string = "hello"; return strlen(string); }` with GCC. It spews a bunch of warnings, from `strlen` being implicitly declared to the implicit pointer-to-integer conversion to the unused parameters. There are no errors, however, and it compiles successfully.

Comment: @icktoofay That explains it. I always compile warnings-as-errors. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: @WhozCraig C isn't so strictly typed as C++. The OP would have certainly got a warning, ignored it and come here to ask a question, should be shot, etc...